# SQL JOIN- user selection which are not blocked by current user

Tags: sql, inner-join

```
SELECT * FROM User
INNER JOIN BlockUser ON BlockUser.userId='1' and User.userId != BlockUser.blockID
```

I have two table one is of “**Users**” table and **BlockUser** table.

I need to select all users from user table  except those which a particular user blocked

User table

```
userID  userName  nickName
1       abc       abc
2       adc       adc
3       dc        dc
4       xyz       xyz
5       qwe       qwe
```

BlockUser

```
_Id  userId  blockID
1      1       2
2      1       3
```

Result

```
userID  userName  nickName
4       xyz       xyz
5       qwe       qwe
```

please help me correct my Sql query.

Comment: User table=>
userID  userName  nickName
1       abc       abc
2       adc       adc
3       dc        dc
4       xyz       xyz
5       qwe       qwe

BlockUser =>
_Id  userId  BlockID
1      1       2
2      1       3

Result 
userID  userName  nickName
4       xyz       xyz
5       qwe       qwe

Comment: What is your question? Add it (edit in) to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @blocker int = 1
SELECT * FROM [User]
WHERE [User].userID NOT IN (SELECT BlockUser.blockID FROM BlockUser WHERE BlockUser.blockID = [User].userID AND BlockUser.userID = @blocker)
AND userID <> @blocker
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a7012/14

The error was also the SQL keyword which is the name of the table, change the name of the table user or use the brackets as shown.

There are also other solutions (from other users but deleted):

```
select u.*
from [User] u
left join BlockUser bu on bu.blockID = u.userID
                      and bu.userId = 1
where bu.userID is null
      and u.userID <> 1;

select * from [user]
where userID <> 1
and userID not in 
  (select blockID from BlockUser 
   where userID = 1);
```

**EDIT 1:** fixed query
**EDIT 2:** nailed it - not :)
**EDIT 3:** accounting for removing blocker from result, using variable
**EDIT 4:** added other solutions

Comment: not getting desired result , it results all the rows from user table .

Comment: try with the new query

Comment: getting extra row of userid 1 in result.

Comment: now it should work check the fiddle, i just mixed up a row as I was making the query off my head.

Comment: result should have 2 rows , in fiddle its 3 . its should also remove userId 1 also . btw thanks .

Comment: it's not  . check again  :(

Comment: added a fix using variable

Comment: Thanks fsacer :) not have enough reputations to upvote answer :(

Answer (score 0):

Your query will be as below:
select userID,userName,nickName from Users where userID NOT IN(Select blockID from  BlockUser where userId =1 );

Comment: getting extra row of userid 1 in result.

Answer (score 0):

Change the join type to an outer join then filter the user table for not null records.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from user 
where userId <> '1'
and userid not in 
  (select blocked from BlockUser.userId 
   where userId = '1')
```